# Trouble finding which customer bought iphone or HTC using SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find which customer bought phones. If the customer bought iPhone only or iPhone and HTC then I need data for iPhone only. But if the customer bought only HTC I would need data for HTC.

**Original Data**

[image]

**Expected output table**

[image]

My code does not work and I'm not sure how to use the where clause. Could you please direct me on where I'm making a mistake?

Below is my code:

```
select Cust_ID, Year, Month, Product from custTable where Item_ID = (
Case 
when Item_ID in ('iPhone','HTC') then 'iPhone'
else 'HTC'
End )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from original o
where o.product = 'iPhone' or
      (o.product = 'HTC' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from original o2
                   where o2.cust_id = o.cust_id and
                         o2.product = 'iPhone'
                  )
      );
```

This is almost a direct translation of your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select  v1.Cust_ID,
        v1.Year,
        v1.Month,
        substring(min(Product),4,1000)  as  Product
from    (
            select  Cust_ID,
                    Year,
                    Month,
                    case when Product in ('iPhone') then '1. iPhone'
                        when Product in ('HTC') then '2. HTC'
                        else Product
                    end as  Product
            from    custTable
        ) v1
group by v1.Cust_ID,
        v1.Year,
        v1.Month
```

Or this:

```
select  v1.Cust_ID,
        v1.Year,
        v1.Month,
        v1.Product
from    (
            select  Cust_ID,
                    Year,
                    Month,
                    Product,
                    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Cust_ID, Year, Month order by case when Product = 'iPhone' then 1 when Product = 'HTC' then 2 else 999 end)  as  rn
            from    custTable
        ) v1
where   v1.rn = 1
```